# NHibernate Abstract Repository ISession Property in Concrete Class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am not sure how to ask my question, so I will write a few lines of code ...

I have an abstract base class **AbstractRepository** like this:

```
 public abstract class AbstractRepository : IGenericRepository
    {       
        protected ISession Session
        {
            get
            {
                return Startup.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
            }            
        }
          
        //More code left out for clarity
}
```

A concrete class that implements the abstract class, AbstractRepository :

```
 public class AccommodationRepository : AbstractRepository
    {                                                
        // Allow the Session property to be returned from the base class.
        public ISession Session => base.Session;
        
        // Which I understand to be the same as the line below:
        // public ISession session { get { return base.Session; } }

        public async Task<EPICCard> GetByCardNumber(long epicCardId)
        {
            var session = Session;
            
            CancellationTokenSource token = new CancellationTokenSource();
           
            //Do stuff - not important for now.

            return theQueryTask.Result;
        }
    }
```

Re-Sharper suggests the following change for the line:

> public ISession Session => base.Session;

TO

> public new ISession Session => base.Session;

[image: ReSharper Prompt]

Which one would should I use and why?

Can someone perhaps explain the reasoning for one over the other? Not sure if this is a lack of understanding of

1. OOP,
2. NHibernate plumbing
3. Or both?

What is the reasoning for creating a 'new' ISession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override a method unless it is `abstract` or `virtual`, so by doing this:

```
public ISession Session => base.Session;
```

You are hiding the base implementation rather than overriding it.

This causes the property's `get` implementation to be selected based on the reference rather than the instance.

In your specific example this makes little difference, however, here is an example where it would:

```
public class AccommodationRepository : AbstractRepository
{
    public ISession Session => new SomeOtherSession();

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        AbstractRepository thisAsAbstract = this;
        object.ReferenceEquals(this.Session, thisAsAbstract.Session); // false
    }
}
```

This happens because `thisAsAbstract.Session` uses the base implementation of `Session` as it has only been hidden.

The suggestion by ReSharper (to use the `new` keyword) is simply to make explicit that method hiding was intended rather than accidental, as in your case it seems to be (because you are changing the access modifier).

Comment: Succinct and well-presented explanation Cudos. I don't fully comprehend/understand the implications of "this causes the property's get implementation to be selected based on the reference rather than the instance." I'm still chewing on it.